# Can I ask what a term in documentation means?

Tags: discussion, support, scope

I want to ask a question about a Python library's document in which there are two professional terms I don't understand. How to understand the `individual room` and `individual client` in [python-socketio doc](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

> The individual rooms assigned to clients when they connect are not special in any way, the application is free to add or remove clients from them, though once it does that it will lose the ability to address individual clients.

May I ask this type of question of Stack Overflow?

Comment: You don't know what a client is? As for "individual", look in a dictionary. Generally, it's not appropriate to ask what a word means on SO unless it doesn't appear to mean what it means in everyday usage (such as "room" in this case, but since the page you link to explains it as well I really don't think a question needs to be posted at all).

Comment: @BoltClock I know the `individual` word meaning, I know the `client` meaning. but I am not understand the `individual client` in the document. the `individual client` is a term in the document.

Comment: It doesn't mean anything special. It's just what you understand about the word "individual", plus what you understand about the word "client".

Comment: I mean, yeah, you can ask about an individual term in documentation, but be responsible about it... this individual question seems kind of obvious to be at Stack Overflow. That said, a user is the client, and a user is also an individual client. This all seems kind of straightforward.

Comment: @Travis J: Stop, you're going to give them a headache using that word over and over again!